# Есть ли во Vue возможность комбинировать два соседних тега в один компонент как в React (<></>)

Tags: vue.js

Хочу узнать, если во Vue Js какой-то способ обернуть два соседних div в один компонент без корневого элемента.
В React например это можно сделать с помощью пустых тегов

```
<>
  <div>
    // layout
  </div>
  <div>
    // layout
  </div>
</>
```

Во Vue пока такой возможности не смог найти в документации

Comment: оберните в тег `template`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь идёт про Vue 2-й версии — ответ будет нет. Во второй версии поддержки нескольких элементов в основном `<template>` не предусматривается.

Решением для второй версии может быть *обварачивание* этих `<div>`-ов в ещё один `<div>`.

Если речь идёт про Vue 3-й версии, то можно добавлять любое количество элементов в основной `<template>`.

Comment: Спасибо!
Возможно вы знаете, где можно найти ссылку на информацию, почему Vue 2 требует наличия родительского тега. Мне интересно узнать процесс такого поведения. Буду благодарен.

Comment: Наиболее подробная информация по этому вопросу есть на GitHub по Vue.js https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7088